# Angular .config routing not working: white page after grunt serve

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

When I run `grunt serve`, nothing but a blank page with scroll bar is shown. I am certain the problem is related to my setup of the .config routing in app.js, but I've struggled for a terribly long time trying to figure out what it is.

**index.html**

> ```
> <!doctype html> <html class="no-js" ng-app="bcApp">   <head>
> <meta charset="utf-8">
> <title>QuickMath</title>
> <meta name="description" content="">
> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
> <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
> <!-- Adds mathjax in asciimath form-->
> <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/MathJax/MathJax.js?config=AM_HTMLorMML-full"></script>
> <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
> <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
> <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
> <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
> <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
> <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
> <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
> <script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
> <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
> <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
> <script src="scripts/controllers.js"></script>   </head>   <body>
> <!--[if lt IE 7]>
>   <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> > browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your >browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
>
> <![endif]-->
>
> <div ng-view class="view-frame"></div>   
> </body> 
> </html>
> ```

**app.js**

```
'use strict';

/* App Module */

var myApp = angular.module('bcApp', [
  'ngAnimate',
  'ngCookies',
  'ngResource',
  'ngRoute',
  'ngSanitize',
  'ngTouch',
  'controllers'
]);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', 
  function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {templateUrl: 'views/home.html', controller: 'HomeCtrl'})
      .when('/theTeam', {templateUrl: 'views/theTeam.html', controller: 'HomeCtrl'})
      .when('/blog', {templateUrl: 'views/blog.html',controller: 'HomeCtrl'})
      .when('/contribute', {templateUrl: 'views/contribute.html',controller: 'HomeCtrl'})
      .when('/algebra', {templateUrl: 'views/algebra.html',controller: 'HomeCtrl'})
      .when('/geometry', {templateUrl: 'views/geometry.html',controller: 'HomeCtrl'})
      .when('/preCalculus', {templateUrl: 'views/preCalculus.html',controller: 'HomeCtrl'})
      .when('/bc', {templateUrl: 'views/bc.html',controller: 'HomeCtrl'})
      .when('/graphTheory', {templateUrl: 'views/graphTheory.html',controller: 'HomeCtrl'})
      .when('/linearAlgebra', {templateUrl: 'views/linearAlgebra.html',controller: 'HomeCtrl'})
      .when('/mvc', {templateUrl: 'views/mvc.html',controller: 'HomeCtrl'})
      .when('/numberTheory', {templateUrl: 'views/numberTheory.html',controller: 'HomeCtrl'})
      .when('/discrete', {templateUrl: 'views/discrete.html',controller: 'HomeCtrl'})
      .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/'});
  }]);
```

**controllers.js**

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */

var app = angular.module('bcApp', ['ngMaterial']);


app.controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];

});

app.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout, $mdSidenav, $mdUtil, $log){
    function buildToggler(navId){
    var debounceFn = $mdUtil.debounce(function (){
        $mdSidenav(navId)
            .toggle()
            .then(function (){
                $log.debug('toggle '  + navId + ' Is done');
            });
        }, 300);
    return debounceFn;
    }

    $scope.toggleLeft = buildToggler('left');
});

app.controller('LeftCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout, $mdSidenav, $log){
    $scope.close = function (){
        $mdSidenav('left').close()
            .then(function () {
                $log.debug('close LEFT is done');
            });
    };
});
```

Comment: You are adding `controllers` module to `bcApp` but i am not seeing any module called `controllers` defined. And your code `var app = angular.module('bcApp', ['ngMaterial']);` will create a new module called `bcApp` again. That means you are overriding the existing one which has routes configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Two issues:**

- You are adding `controllers` module to `bcApp` but i am not seeing any module called controllers defined.
- Your code `var app = angular.module('bcApp', ['ngMaterial']);` will create a new module called `bcApp` again. That means you are overriding the existing one which has routes configured.

Change the module name to `controllers` that actually has controllers code.

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */

var app = angular.module('controllers', ['ngMaterial']);


app.controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];

});

app.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout, $mdSidenav, $mdUtil, $log){
    function buildToggler(navId){
    var debounceFn = $mdUtil.debounce(function (){
        $mdSidenav(navId)
            .toggle()
            .then(function (){
                $log.debug('toggle '  + navId + ' Is done');
            });
        }, 300);
    return debounceFn;
    }

    $scope.toggleLeft = buildToggler('left');
});

app.controller('LeftCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout, $mdSidenav, $log){
    $scope.close = function (){
        $mdSidenav('left').close()
            .then(function () {
                $log.debug('close LEFT is done');
            });
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy help!

Answer (score 0):

Here, you are creating angular module with two different variable name :

```
var myApp = angular.module();
```

and

```
var app = angular.module();
```

and within controller you are using "app" module for controller and "myApp" for routing.

so first make one module and used it at both the place.